# bash globbing in subprocess

Tags: python, bash

If I have a directory in which I want to delete all but one file, I might do this in bash:

```
cd /tmp/a
rm -rf !(specialfile)
cd -
```

Translating this to the most obvious Python code fails for me:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen( 'cd /tmp/a; rm -rf !(specialfile); cd -', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

with this message:

```
('', "/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cd /tmp/a; rm -rf !(specialfile); cd -'\n")
```

The next best thing in Python seems to be:

```
p = '/tmp/a'
    for i in os.listdir( p ):
    if i != 'specialfile':
        os.remove( os.path.join( p, i ) )
```

but of course this doesn't handle files and subdirectories equally well.  Is there a better way?

Comment: have you tried: `subprocess.Popen( 'bash -c "cd /tmp/a; rm -rf !(specialfile)"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()`, reason being that `shell=True` invokes `/bin/sh` not bash (may or may not be different, depending on the system).

Comment: take a look at: [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). Also, reading from the docs for [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) you can pass the `executable` argument to specify the shell that should be used, which should solve your first attempt.

Comment: Personally, I like the "next best thing" better - spawning a bash just to clean a hierarchy seems excessive.  To deal with directories, you can use shutil.rmtree().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use os.walk as @Bakuriu mentioned. Very important is to traverse the directory tree from bottom to top in order to have always empty directories, with the exception of the one containing the 'specialfile'. That's why you would need the `try` clause in the `os.rmdir` command.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if name != 'specialfile':
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        try:
            os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  I posted my solution along with a simple test [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22448874/1698426).

Comment: Great @John Schmitt ! Always happy to help. But, do not forget to mark the answer as the selected one. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: As @isedev and OP @JohnSchmitt point out in comments, `subprocess.Popen` invokes `sh`, not `bash` (and `sh` may or may not be `bash`, depending on the platform), but use of the extended pattern matching operator `!(...)` requires (a) `bash` with (b) the `extglob` option turned on (see below for background).

Thus, the answer is to:

- invoke `bash` explicitly with a command string passed via the `-c` command-line option.
- turn on the `extglob` shell option, via the `-O` command-line option (without it, the glob `!(specialfile)` triggers the syntax error the OP encountered).

Borrowing from @JohnSchmitt's own comment, we get:

```
subprocess.Popen("bash -O extglob -c 'cd /tmp/a; rm -rf !(file2); cd -'",
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()
```

(The less elegant alternative is to add `shopt -s extglob;` to the bash command string, before the `rm` command.)

**Background**:

`!(specialfile)` is an instance of an *extended* pattern matching operator (see `man bash`, section `Pattern Matching`); these extended operators are by default NOT enabled; `shopt -s extglob` enables them (`shopt -u extglob` disables them).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The only way I got it to work was this way: `subprocess.Popen( "bash -O extglob -c 'cd /tmp/a; rm -rf !(file2); cd -'", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True ).communicate()`

Comment: @JohnSchmitt: Thanks for the feedback - should have noticed that `.Popen` uses `sh`, not `bash`. With `bash -c`, incorporating `shopt -s extglob` in the command string should work, but your `-O extglob` approach is actually more elegant; I'll update my answer.